# SQL Query: Find the name of the company that has been assigned the highest number of patents

Tags: sql, oracle

[image: Following is the schema of Database]

Using this query I can find the Company Assignee number for company with most patents but I can't seem to print the company name.

```
SELECT count(*), patent.assignee
FROM Patent
GROUP BY patent.assignee
HAVING count(*) =
    (SELECT max(count(*))
    FROM Patent
    Group by patent.assignee);
```

COUNT(*) --- ASSIGNEE

```
 9  19715
 9  27895
```

Nesting above query into

```
SELECT company.compname
FROM company
WHERE ( company.assignee = ( *above query* ) );
```

would give an error "too many values" since there are two companies with most patents but above query takes only one assignee number in the WHERE clause. How do I solve this problem? I need to print name of BOTH companies with assignee number 19715 and 27895. Thank you.

Comment: `I need to print name of BOTH companies with assignee number 19715 and 27895` ... what does this have to do with the count?  Edit your question to show sample data and your desired output.

Comment: Wait, is this MySQL or Oracle? Why tag both?

Comment: To fix the query the way you started it, in the last code section (after "Nesting above query into") you need to use the IN condition instead of the = sign. Something like "where x in (1, 2, 3)" rather than "where x = (1, 2, 3)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have started down the path of using nested queries.  All you need to do is remove `COUNT(*)`:

```
SELECT company.compname
FROM company
WHERE company.assignee IN 
          (SELECT patent.assignee
           FROM Patent
           GROUP BY patent.assignee
           HAVING count(*) = (SELECT max(count(*))
                              FROM Patent
                              GROUP BY patent.assignee
                             )
          );
```

I wouldn't write the query this way.  The use of `max(count(*))` is particularly jarring, but it is valid Oracle syntax.

Comment: Me neither; nice to learn something new (if maybe not that useful). I guess the construct could have been removed by adding another subquery level though.

Comment: As the OP stated, the middle query may (and in his case will) return more than one row. In the third row of code, replace `=` with `IN` - that's really what you are looking for.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Thank you! Although I would like to know why are you discouraging from using max(count(*))?

Comment: @MuhammadZainQasmi . . . That is an Oracle-specific syntax.  It really bothers me that it affects the number of rows returned by an aggregation query.  I would rather use a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Applying an aggregate function on another aggregate function (like `max(count(*))`) is illegal in many databases but I believe using the `ALL` operator instead and a join to get the company name would solve your problem.

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), p.assignee, c.compname
FROM Patent p
JOIN Company c ON c.assignee = p.assignee
GROUP BY p.assignee, c.compname
HAVING COUNT(*) >= ALL     -- this predicate will return those rows 
    (                      -- for which the comparison holds true 
    SELECT COUNT(*)        -- for all instances.
    FROM Patent            -- it can only be true for the highest count
    GROUP BY assignee
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Oracle, I thought about this a bit differently:

```
select
    c.compname
from
    company c
join
    (
        select
            assignee,
            dense_rank() over (order by count(1) desc) rnk
        from
            patent
        group by
            assignee
    ) p
    on p.assignee = c.assignee
where
    p.rnk = 1
;
```

I like this because is lets you find the any rank. For example, if you want the top 3 you would just change p.rnk = 1 to p.rnk <= 3. If you want 10th place, you just change it to p.rnk = 10. Adding the total count and rank into the results would be easy from here too. Overall I think it's more versatile.